# Same height element at screen-bottom in Chrome Mobile in non-fullscreen and fullscreen mode

Tags: css, google-chrome

My question is two-fold:

1. Is it possible to avoid fullscreen on Chrome mobile? Now when an
   element is swiped upward the URL box on top shift up and the browser
   goes into fullscreen. I would like it to stay 'non-fullscreen'. As
   'forcing fullscreen' is pretty well documented, i.e. only dirty/
   temporary hacks and not really supported, I suppose the reverse is
   also 'not supported'. Which leads me to
2. I would like to have an element stay at the bottom of my screen and
   keep the same height (A) both in non-fullscreen and fullscreen mode.

So in non-fullscreen it looks like this:

[image]

And in fullscreen it looks like this:

[image]

Is this possible? How?

Comment: so what you want is a non sticky header menu and a sticky footer bar...actually don't worry, not a header menu...you want a sticky footer bar and display url section.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But without sharing your best attempt at coding this yourself, you are, by definition, a client, not a coder, and that would make your question *off-topic* on this website. Please update the question with the relevant parts of your code (ideally a *runnable* [mcve]).

Comment: @Mindless That's right, a sticky footer bar!